# Не происходит запись в таблицу SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Я пытаюсь создать для своего приложения страницу регистрации/авторизации. В базе данных дополнительно создаю таблицу для пользователей. На activity с регистрацией, после нажатия кнопки "Зарегистрироваться" хочу выполнить проверку существует ли пользователь с таким email в базе или нет. И есть нет, то введенные данные должны быть записаны в таблицу. Проверка вроде как происходит, но результат всегда отрицательный, мне кажется, что данные просто не записываются в таблицу. Никак не могу понять почему.

**База данных.** Проверка введенных данных - **Exist**

```
public class DB {
//название и версия БД
private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
int remember_id = 1;

//столбцы для таблицы событий и создание таблицы
private static final String DB_TABLE_EVENTS = "mytab";
public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_TIME = "time";
public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS =
        "create table " + DB_TABLE_EVENTS + "(" +
                EVENTS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                EVENTS_COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " +
                EVENTS_COLUMN_DATE + " text, " +
                EVENTS_COLUMN_TIME + " text, " +
                EVENTS_COLUMN_ADDRESS + " text, " +
                EVENTS_COLUMN_PHONE + " text, " +
                EVENTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text" +
                ");";

//столбцы для таблицы пользователей и создание таблицы
private static final String DB_TABLE_USERS = "users_tab";
public static final String USERS_COLOMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String USERS_COLOMN_LOGIN = "login";
public static final String USERS_COLOMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String USERS_COLOMN_PASSWORD = "pass";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS =
        "create table " + DB_TABLE_USERS + "(" +
                USERS_COLOMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                USERS_COLOMN_LOGIN + " text, " +
                USERS_COLOMN_EMAIL + " text, " +
                USERS_COLOMN_PASSWORD + " text" +
                ");";

//столбцы для таблицы списка и создание таблицы
private static final String DB_TABLE_LIST = "list_tab";
public static final String LIST_COLOMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String USERLIST_COLOMN_ID = "_id_user";
public static final String EVENTLIST_COLOMN_ID = "_id_event";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LIST =
        "create table " + DB_TABLE_LIST + "(" +
                LIST_COLOMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                USERLIST_COLOMN_ID + " integer not null ,foreign key ("+USERLIST_COLOMN_ID+") reference "+DB_TABLE_USERS+" ("+USERS_COLOMN_ID+"), " +
                EVENTLIST_COLOMN_ID + " integer not null ,foreign key ("+EVENTLIST_COLOMN_ID+") reference "+DB_TABLE_EVENTS+" ("+EVENTS_COLUMN_ID+")" +
                ");";

private final Context mCtx;
private DBHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
public DB(Context ctx) {
    mCtx = ctx;
}

// открыть подключение
public void open() {
    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

// закрыть подключение
public void close() {
    if (mDBHelper!=null) mDBHelper.close();
}

// получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE_EVENTS
public Cursor getAllData() {
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE_EVENTS, null, null, null, null, null, "_id DESC");
}

//получаем объект по id из таблицы DB_TABLE_EVENTS
public Cursor getEventById(long id) {
    return mDB.query("mytab", null, "_id = " + id, null, null, null, "_id DESC");
}

//проверяем существует ли пользователь
public String Exist(String user) {
    String username="";
    try {
        Cursor c =  mDB.query(DB_TABLE_USERS, null, USERS_COLOMN_EMAIL + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(user)},null, null, null);

        if (c == null) {
            return username;
        }
        else {
            c.moveToFirst();
            username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(USERS_COLOMN_EMAIL));
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return username;
}

// добавить запись в DB_TABLE_EVENTS
public void addRecEvent(String tit, String dat, String tim, String adr, String phn, String dsc) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_TITLE, tit);
    cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_DATE, dat);
    cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_TIME, tim);
    cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_ADDRESS, adr);
    cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_PHONE, phn);
    cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, dsc);
    mDB.insert(DB_TABLE_EVENTS, null, cv);
}

// добавить запись в DB_TABLE_USERS
public void addRecUsers(String login, String email, String pass) {
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(USERS_COLOMN_EMAIL, email);
    cv2.put(USERS_COLOMN_LOGIN, login);
    cv2.put(USERS_COLOMN_PASSWORD, pass);
    mDB.insert(DB_TABLE_USERS, null, cv2);
}

// удалить запись из DB_TABLE_EVENTS
public void delRec(long id) {
    mDB.delete(DB_TABLE_EVENTS, EVENTS_COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
}

// класс по созданию и управлению БД
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                    int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    // создаем и заполняем БД
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
            cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_TITLE, "Увлекательное событие");
            cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_DATE, "Каждый день");
            cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_TIME, "каждый час");
            cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_ADDRESS, "где-то");
            cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_PHONE, "спросите у нас.");
            cv.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, "происходит что-то интересное. Не пропустите самые интересные события вашего города!");
            db.insert(DB_TABLE_EVENTS, null, cv);
        }

        ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
            cv2.put(USERS_COLOMN_LOGIN, "superuser");
            cv2.put(USERS_COLOMN_EMAIL, "dasha");
            cv2.put(USERS_COLOMN_PASSWORD, "12345");
            db.insert(DB_TABLE_USERS, null, cv2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

}

**Activity**, где происходит регистрация:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etRegEmail, etRegLogin, etRegPassword;
Button btnRegister, btnLoginLink;
TextView tvSiteLink;
DB db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    etRegEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegEmail);
    etRegLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegLogin);
    etRegPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister23);
    btnLoginLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginLink);
    tvSiteLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSiteLink);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLoginLink.setOnClickListener(this);

    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnRegister23:
            String email = (etRegEmail.getText().toString());
            String login = (etRegLogin.getText().toString());
            String pass = (etRegPassword.getText().toString());
            String storedUser = db.Exist(email);
            if (email.equals(storedUser)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Вы уже зарегистрированы. Пожалуйста, авторизируйтесь.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else db.addRecUsers(email, login, pass);
            break;
        case R.id.btnLoginLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: вы объявили `addRecUsers(String login, String email, String pass)`, а вызываете `db.addRecUsers(email, login, pass);` login и email местами поменяли.

Comment: Какая ужасно глупая ошибка, спасибо большое, сама бы не заметила ни за что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените

```
if (c == null) {
    return username;
}
```

на

```
if (c == null || c.getCount() == 0) {
    return username;
}
```